# How do I escape an ampersand in a Socrata SODA 2 API call?

Tags: socrata, soda

I am working with the [NYC crime dataset](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-7-Major-Felony-Incidents/hyij-8hr7) and I notice that the `offense` type for homicides is `MURDER & NON-NEGL. MANSLAUGHTE`. (Yes, that’s “manslaughte” without the “r”.) However, when I try to filter for this using the SODA API, I get errors:

> `https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/hyij-8hr7.json?$where=offense='MURDER & NON-NEGL. MANSLAUGHTE'`
>
> > {
> >       "error" : true,
> >       "message" : "Unrecognized arguments [ NON-NEGL. MANSLAUGHTE']"
> >     }

It seems to me that the ampersand in the string is escaping.

Note that I tried to use the `like=‘MURDER’` command to avoid needing to type the ampersand, so for instance querying `https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/hyij-8hr7.json?$where=offense like 'MURDER'`, but this gives me the error

> {
>     "error" : true,
>     "message" : "Error: function #LIKE is not defined in SoQL.: Error: function #LIKE is not defined in SoQL.”
>   }

This must mean that the NYC dataset is using SoQL. v. 2.0 and not 2.1.

So in conclusion, how can I query for homicides? Is there a way to *either* (a) properly escape the ampersand, or (b) search for substrings?

Thanks for any assistance on either of these requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, `hyij-8hr7` is the SODA 2.0 endpoint for that dataset. However, a 2.1 endpoint also exists: https://dev.socrata.com/foundry/data.cityofnewyork.us/e4qk-cpnv

Using the 2.1 endpoint, you can escape the ampersand as a URL-encoded `%26`: `$where=offense='MURDER %26 NON-NEGL. MANSLAUGHTE'`. Full URL, fully-escaped:

`GET https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/e4qk-cpnv.json?$where=offense%3D%27MURDER%20%26%20NON-NEGL.%20MANSLAUGHTE%27`

With the 2.1 endpoint, you can also use [`LIKE`](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/like.html) to do SQL-style substring searches or [`$q`](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries/q.html) to use the full-text search index.